# Using transform() and calc() in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, transform

Am I missing something obvious, or does firefox not like using calc() inside transform:skewY() ?

## The problem

the following transform works, no problem :

```
body article {
    postion:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform-origin:left;
    transform:skewY(-15deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

however trying to use calc() doesn't. Not in firefox in any rate, although chrome renders the skew() as expected :

```
body article {
    postion:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform-origin:left;
    transform:skewY(calc(-1rad * 3.14 / 12)) translateY(-50%);
}
```

I would usually assume that this is something that firefox doesn't do, but their official documentation says :

> The calc() CSS function can be used anywhere a length, frequency, angle, time, number, or integer is required.

( source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility )

So I'm thinking that the fault is mine. Can anyone see something wrong with the syntax in the transform ?

## the context

```
<html>
    <body>
        <article>
            <header>title</header>
            <div>article content</div>
        </article

        <!-- more articles... -->

    </body>
</html>
```

with css that looks something like this :

```
body {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
body article {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
}
body article header {
    height:50px;
}
body article div {
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is accurately line up the skewed elements in a horizontal gallery. I'm also open to any lateral thinking =)

Comment: @t.niese Ah, thank you for finding that out, I don't feel quite as dumb. I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Martin Thanks to the late, great Douglas Adams =)

Comment: Absolutely. I heard he won an award for Norway `;-)`

Comment: My name's not important. You must come with me, or you'll be late.
Late for what?
Well, um, what's your name Earthman?
Dent. Arthur Dent.
Well, late as in *the late* Dentarthurdent. It's a sort of threat. You see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Bug 956573 - calc() CSS function doesn't work with all data types (units) that it should, such as times](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956573) (from 2014 but still open) in the issue tracker.

One comment (also from 2014) has a code snipped with the comment `// calc() currently allows only lengths and percents inside it.`

Because there is no further comment that more units are support now and also given the fact that the comment is still in the current source (49.0.1) including a further limitation `And note that in current implementation, number cannot be mixed with length and percent.` I would assume that it is still the case, that Firefox still does only support lengths and percents.

```
if ((aVariantMask & VARIANT_CALC) &&
    IsCSSTokenCalcFunction(*tk)) {
  // calc() currently allows only lengths and percents and number inside it.
  // And note that in current implementation, number cannot be mixed with
  // length and percent.
  if (!ParseCalc(aValue, aVariantMask & VARIANT_LPN)) {
    return CSSParseResult::Error;
  }
  return CSSParseResult::Ok;
}
```