# Use calc() in transform:rotate()

Tags: css, rotation, calc

How to use `calc()` to determine the angle value for `transform:rotate()`?

The [!mdn docs for the CSS `calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) states:

> The `calc()` CSS function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is required. With `calc()`, you can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

However, using `calc()` to create an angle value for `transform:rotate()` isn't working for me.

The suggestion of [this blog doesn't work](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/getting-started-css-calc-techniques/) -- `transform: rotate(calc(1turn - 32deg));`, nor similar variants of operations using `calc()` in this way.

See [this codepen for verification](http://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/ggYzKp) - only the fifth `<div>` rotates as expected **and** doesn't use `calc()` to determine the angle.

Here is the main code from the codepen to show here:

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.one {
  transform: rotate(calc(1turn - 32deg));
}

.two {
  transform: rotate(calc(360deg - 90deg));
}

.three {
  transform: rotate(calc(360deg/4deg));
}

.four {
  transform: rotate(calc(22deg + 23deg));
}

.five {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

This same problem happens for me across the latest Chrome, Firefox Developer Edition, and Safari.

Other discussions related to this problem exist, but don't offer any solution. For example:

- [Using transform() and calc() in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806840/using-transform-and-calc-in-firefox)
- [calc() not working inside color and transform functions](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/931698/ie11-calc-not-working-inside-color-and-transform-functions)

Comment: `360deg/4deg` looks wrong

Comment: You do know that rotating a square by 90° or its increments thereof (in your second and third examples) will not show any discernible difference? The axis of symmetry of a square is 90° apart.

Comment: The only problem you got there is the `360deg/4deg`, and this is because you are looking for `360deg / 4` (note the space and removing the `deg` on the `4`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Spaces matter in `calc()`

**CORRECT:**

```
.three {
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 4));
}
```

**INCORRECT:**

```
.three {
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg/4deg));
}
```

Because 360deg / 4deg == 90 and 360deg / 4 = 90deg. And you are looking for a degrees and not a pure number.

Comment: Can I somehow use units like vw in this calc? `transform: rotate(calc(35deg + 10vw))` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the same problem and have also tried the `calc()` function inside other angular `transform` functions such as skewX and skewY on both Chrome (v59.0) and FF(v54.0). In both cases the `skew` function did not skew as expected.

Note that `calc()` functions used for the family of *length-based* `translate()` transform functions *does* work (see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua8mwgdL/3/)).

The z-direction of `translate3D()` is not working in my Fiddle but you can see how it works using the Codepen link on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d)

Notice how `skewX()` works properly for `#div1` as a hard-coded angle but if you re-write this using `calc()` as an argument (e.g., try `calc(-45deg + 1rad)` ), it breaks the css for `#div1`.